# Paypal api insert the product in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, paypal

ho can i insert in array the products using loop 
example

here i must use loop to add the products of cart

```
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice('7.50');

$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName('Granola bars')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(5)
    ->setPrice('2.00');
```

and this must be the list of all items

```
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));
```

so i must use loop in first to add it in array
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place all items in an array (e.g. with an index counter $_index) like this:

```
$items = array();
$index = 1;
$items[$index] = new Item();
$items[$index]->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
              ->setCurrency('USD')
              ->setQuantity(1)
              ->setPrice('7.50');
$index = 2;
$items[$index] = new Item();
$items[$index]->setName('Granola bars')
              ->setCurrency('USD')
              ->setQuantity(5)
              ->setPrice('2.00');
```

This could also be done in a loop:

```
$items = array();
$index = 0;
foreach ($object_array_with_items as $_item) {
   $index++;
   $items[$index] = new Item();
   $items[$index]->setName($_item['name_key'])
                 ->setCurrency($_item['currency_key'])
                 ->setQuantity($_item['quantity_key'])
                 ->setPrice($_item['price_key']);
}
```

And then you could do

```
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($items);
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Is the used cookie perhaps to big ?

Comment: take a look here i posted it in new subject
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992842/can-not-find-the-error-in-this-code-paypal-api

Answer (score 1):

Erwin van Hoof is almost correct, but missing a vital detail. Erwins solution will create an index in the array hierarchy that PayPal will not understand. So if you are to do it like Erwin suggests, then you will have to create a second array that is sent to PayPal. I would do it like this:

```
$item  = array();
$items = array();
$index = 0;
foreach ($object_array_with_items as $_item) {
   $index++;
   $item[$index] = new Item();
   $item[$index]->setName($_item['name_key'])
                ->setCurrency($_item['currency_key'])
                ->setQuantity($_item['quantity_key'])
                ->setPrice($_item['price_key']);

   $items[] = $item[$index];
}
```

Then this works without the MALFORMED_REQUEST from PayPal:

```
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a little on code from @ change to work.

```
$items = array();
$index = 0;
foreach ($object_array_with_items as $_item) {
   $items[$index] = new Item();
   $items[$index]->setName($_item['name_key'])
                 ->setCurrency($_item['currency_key'])
                 ->setQuantity($_item['quantity_key'])
                 ->setPrice($_item['price_key']);
   $index++;
}
```